# Pivot and aggregate a PySpark Data Frame with alias

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pivot, aggregate-functions, alias

I have a PySpark DataFrame similar to this:

```python
df = sc.parallelize([
    ("c1", "A", 3.4, 0.4, 3.5), 
    ("c1", "B", 9.6, 0.0, 0.0),
    ("c1", "A", 2.8, 0.4, 0.3),
    ("c1", "B", 5.4, 0.2, 0.11),
    ("c2", "A", 0.0, 9.7, 0.3), 
    ("c2", "B", 9.6, 8.6, 0.1),
    ("c2", "A", 7.3, 9.1, 7.0),
    ("c2", "B", 0.7, 6.4, 4.3)
]).toDF(["user_id", "type", "d1", 'd2', 'd3'])
df.show()
```

which gives:

```python
+-------+----+---+---+----+
|user_id|type| d1| d2|  d3|
+-------+----+---+---+----+
|     c1|   A|3.4|0.4| 3.5|
|     c1|   B|9.6|0.0| 0.0|
|     c1|   A|2.8|0.4| 0.3|
|     c1|   B|5.4|0.2|0.11|
|     c2|   A|0.0|9.7| 0.3|
|     c2|   B|9.6|8.6| 0.1|
|     c2|   A|7.3|9.1| 7.0|
|     c2|   B|0.7|6.4| 4.3|
+-------+----+---+---+----+
```

And I've pivoted it by `type` column aggregating the result with a `sum()`:

```python
data_wide = df.groupBy('user_id')\
.pivot('type').sum()
data_wide.show()
```

which gives:

```python
 +-------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+------------------+
|user_id|      A_sum(`d1`)|       A_sum(`d2`)|A_sum(`d3`)|       B_sum(`d1`)|B_sum(`d2`)|       B_sum(`d3`)|
+-------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+------------------+
|     c1|6.199999999999999|               0.8|        3.8|              15.0|        0.2|              0.11|
|     c2|              7.3|18.799999999999997|        7.3|10.299999999999999|       15.0|4.3999999999999995|
+-------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+------------------+-----------+------------------+
```

Now, the resulting column names contains the `(tilde) character, and this is a problem to, for example, introduce this new columns in a Vector Assembler because it returns a `syntax error in attribute name`. For this reason, I need to rename the column names but to call a `withColumnRenamed` method inside a loop or inside a `reduce(lambda...)` function takes a lot of time (actually my df has 11.520 columns).

Is there any way to avoid this character in the pivot+aggregation step or recursively assign an alias that depends on the name of the new pivoted column?

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836877/rename-pivoted-and-aggregated-column-in-pyspark-dataframe

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I've already read the question but here I need to apply the rename process during the pivot step because a posterior rename takes a lot of time.

Comment: @Amanda what about `data_wide = df.groupBy('user_id').pivot('type').agg(*[f.sum(x).alias(x) for x in df.columns if x not in {"user_id", "type"}])` where `f` comes from `import pyspark.sql.functions as f`

Comment: @pault you should place your comment as an answer. Than it is more obvious that this question might be solved. For me it seems a lot like it is. Btw: what is the effect of the "*"?

Comment: @pault, your comment is the answer, please place it as an answer as Thomas R said. Thomas R, the * is to pass each element as an argument. Thank you so much @paul!

Comment: Amanda I will post an answer with an explanation, but the method I suggested is almost no different than the one in the link posted by Konrad. @Thomas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* do the renaming within the aggregation for the `pivot` using [`alias`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=column#pyspark.sql.Column.alias):

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
data_wide = df.groupBy('user_id')\
    .pivot('type')\
    .agg(*[f.sum(x).alias(x) for x in df.columns if x not in {"user_id", "type"}])
data_wide.show()
#+-------+-----------------+------------------+----+------------------+----+------------------+
#|user_id|             A_d1|              A_d2|A_d3|              B_d1|B_d2|              B_d3|
#+-------+-----------------+------------------+----+------------------+----+------------------+
#|     c1|6.199999999999999|               0.8| 3.8|              15.0| 0.2|              0.11|
#|     c2|              7.3|18.799999999999997| 7.3|10.299999999999999|15.0|4.3999999999999995|
#+-------+-----------------+------------------+----+------------------+----+------------------+
```

However, this is really no different than doing the `pivot` and renaming afterwards. Here is the execution plan for this method:

```python
#== Physical Plan ==
#HashAggregate(keys=[user_id#0], functions=[pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d1`) AS `d1`#169, A, B, 0, 0), pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d2`) 
#AS `d2`#170, A, B, 0, 0), pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d3`) AS `d3`#171, A, B, 0, 0)])
#+- Exchange hashpartitioning(user_id#0, 200)
#   +- HashAggregate(keys=[user_id#0], functions=[partial_pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d1`) AS `d1`#169, A, B, 0, 0), partial_pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d2`) AS `d2`#170, A, B, 0, 0), partial_pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d3`) AS `d3`#171, A, B, 0, 0)])
#      +- *HashAggregate(keys=[user_id#0, type#1], functions=[sum(d1#2), sum(d2#3), sum(d3#4)])
#         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(user_id#0, type#1, 200)
#            +- *HashAggregate(keys=[user_id#0, type#1], functions=[partial_sum(d1#2), partial_sum(d2#3), partial_sum(d3#4)])
#               +- Scan ExistingRDD[user_id#0,type#1,d1#2,d2#3,d3#4]
```

Compare this with the method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37842998/5858851):

```python
import re

def clean_names(df):
    p = re.compile("^(\w+?)_([a-z]+)\((\w+)\)(?:\(\))?")
    return df.toDF(*[p.sub(r"\1_\3", c) for c in df.columns])

pivoted = df.groupBy('user_id').pivot('type').sum()
clean_names(pivoted).explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#HashAggregate(keys=[user_id#0], functions=[pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d1`)#363, A, B, 0, 0), pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d2`)#364, A, B, 0, 0), pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d3`)#365, A, B, 0, 0)])
#+- Exchange hashpartitioning(user_id#0, 200)
#   +- HashAggregate(keys=[user_id#0], functions=[partial_pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d1`)#363, A, B, 0, 0), partial_pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d2`)#364, A, B, 0, 0), partial_pivotfirst(type#1, sum(`d3`)#365, A, B, 0, 0)])
#      +- *HashAggregate(keys=[user_id#0, type#1], functions=[sum(d1#2), sum(d2#3), sum(d3#4)])
#         +- Exchange hashpartitioning(user_id#0, type#1, 200)
#            +- *HashAggregate(keys=[user_id#0, type#1], functions=[partial_sum(d1#2), partial_sum(d2#3), partial_sum(d3#4)])
#               +- Scan ExistingRDD[user_id#0,type#1,d1#2,d2#3,d3#4]
```

You'll see that the two are practically identical. You'll likely have some minuscule speed up by avoiding the regular expression, but it will be negligible compared to the `pivot`.

Comment: Thank you @pault. I don't know the reason why because as you say, the execution plan is almost the same, but in practice the second option takes much more time than the first one. I don't understand where the `clean_names` is represented in the second case, in the first one the rename is clearly applied to each `sum` via `AS`, but I don't understand the equivalent in the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote an easy and fast function to rename PySpark pivot tables. Enjoy! :)

```
# This function efficiently rename pivot tables' urgly names
def rename_pivot_cols(rename_df, remove_agg):
    """change spark pivot table's default ugly column names at ease.
        Option 1: remove_agg = True: `2_sum(sum_amt)` --> `sum_amt_2`.
        Option 2: remove_agg = False: `2_sum(sum_amt)` --> `sum_sum_amt_2`
    """
    for column in rename_df.columns:
        if remove_agg == True:
            start_index = column.find('(')
            end_index = column.find(')')
            if (start_index > 0 and end_index > 0):
                rename_df = rename_df.withColumnRenamed(column, column[start_index+1:end_index]+'_'+column[:1])
        else:
            new_column = column.replace('(','_').replace(')','')
            rename_df = rename_df.withColumnRenamed(column, new_column[2:]+'_'+new_column[:1])   
    return rename_df
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Zilong Z! I tried this option (changing the column names within a loop) but it took a long time, my df had more than 11500 columns and the option to rename using an alias within the aggregation is much faster. However, this answer clarifies the option of the loop. Thank you!