# Combine pivoting and groupby aggregating in PySpark Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, pivot-table, aggregate, etl

I am re-using the example in [Combine pivoted and aggregated column in PySpark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57191369/combine-pivoted-and-aggregated-column-in-pyspark-dataframe)

Say I have a Spark Dataframe

```
 date      | recipe | percent | volume
----------------------------------------
2019-01-01 |   A    |  0.03   |  53
2019-01-01 |   A    |  0.02   |  55
2019-01-01 |   B    |  0.05   |  60
2019-01-02 |   A    |  0.11   |  75
2019-01-02 |   B    |  0.06   |  64
2019-01-02 |   B    |  0.08   |  66
```

How do I pivot on one column and aggregate on another like the following pseudo-code:

```
df.groupBy('date').max('volume').alias('max_volume').pivot('recipe').agg(avg('percent').alias('percent')).show()

 date      | A_percent | B_percent | max_volume
--------------------------------------------------------
2019-01-01 |   0.025   |  0.05     |  60
2019-01-02 |   0.11    |  0.07     |  75
```

I'd like to achieve this in one step without having to do max on columns A_volume and B_volume later to avoid naming those columns.

ps.
When I natively run that pseudo-code, I get

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'pivot'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window
var win = Window.partitionBy("date") 
data.withColumn("max_vol",max("volume").over(win)).groupBy("date","max_vol") .pivot("recipe") .agg(avg("percent")).show()
```